# How to judge the limit number of query tasks mentioned in the system message of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Apache IoTDB system reported "the system can't allow more query tasks". I understand that this means the query amount is too much to execute, but I want to ask how this query task limit is judged, through which parameter? Also, how can I check the number of tasks mentioned in this error to avoid this being popped out again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `show queries` statement to take a look at all the query tasks happening in Apache IoTDB. Generally, this error should be caused by the number of concurrent queries exceeds the setting of `max_allowed_concurrent_queries`. You can use this way to check the number of query tasks you have and reset the `max_allowed_concurrent_queries` parameter value if you need.